# From wc_get_order() to REST API data - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Comparing the data returned by `wc_get_order($order)->get_data()` to the data returned by the `wc()->api->get_endpoint_data('/wc/v3/orders/' . $order);` REST endpoint, the data is the same, except for that in the first case, for some keys the data is an object instead of a formatted piece of information.

E.g. `[date_created] => 2022-04-13T10:11:52` returned by REST, is like this

```
[date_created] => WC_DateTime Object
    (
        [utc_offset:protected] => 7200
        [date] => 2022-04-13 08:11:52.000000
        [timezone_type] => 1
        [timezone] => +00:00
    )
```

in the data returned by `wc_get_order()`...

What's the code that "flattens" the data converting it to the one returned by the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Parses and formats a date for ISO8601/RFC3339.
 *
 * Required WP 4.4 or later.
 * See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/mysql_to_rfc3339/
 *
 * @since  2.6.0
 * @param  string|null|WC_DateTime $date Date.
 * @param  bool                    $utc  Send false to get local/offset time.
 * @return string|null ISO8601/RFC3339 formatted datetime.
 */
function wc_rest_prepare_date_response( $date, $utc = true ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $date ) ) {
        $date = new WC_DateTime( "@$date", new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) );
        $date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone( wc_timezone_string() ) );
    } elseif ( is_string( $date ) ) {
        $date = new WC_DateTime( $date, new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) );
        $date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone( wc_timezone_string() ) );
    }

    if ( ! is_a( $date, 'WC_DateTime' ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Get timestamp before changing timezone to UTC.
    return gmdate( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $utc ? $date->getTimestamp() : $date->getOffsetTimestamp() );
}
```